# Derivation of triangular number line segment recurrence relation

Tags: combinatorics, limits, recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients, triangulation

I was reading about triangular numbers on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), where the following statement is made:

> The number of line segments between closest pairs of dots in the triangle can be represented in terms of the number of dots or with a recurrence relation:
>   $$L_n=3T_{n-1}=3\binom{n}2{}; $$
>   $$L_n=L_{n-1}+3(n-1),L_1=0$$
>   In the limit, the ratio between the two numbers, dots and line segments is 
>   $$lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{T_n}{L_n}=\frac{1}{3}$$

I understand how we get $L_n=L_{n-1}+3(n-1),L_1=0$: for every new side we add, we add $3$ line segments for every triangle that can be formed from that new side, and this comes out to $3(n-1)$ more segments for each increment of $L_n$.

However, I don't understand how $$L_n=3T_{n-1}=3\binom{n}2{} $$ and $$lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{T_n}{L_n}=\frac{1}{3}$$ were derived.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $L_n = 3T_{n-1}$, visualize all the small line segments being drawn. Then you will have many small equilateral triangles, $T_{n-1}$ of which point "upward." Each of the small line segments is an edge of exactly one of these "upward" small equilateral triangles, so there are $3 T_{n-1}$ segments.

For the limit,
$$\frac{T_n}{L_n} = \frac{T_n}{3 T_{n-1}} = \frac{1}{3} \frac{n(n-1)}{(n-1)(n-2)} \to \frac{1}{3}.$$

Comment: How come $T_{n-3}$ of the triangles point "upward"? It's visibly "true", but is there an way to show this? Some trivial combinatorial (or otherwise) proof?

Comment: @Princee The top vertices of these "upward" triangles form a diagram of points corresponding to the picture for the triangular number $T_{n-1}$. Sorry, there was a typo.